# webdriver fetch element of following class after match in selenium webdriver

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I have the following example where I have to fetch the value of class after a match is found in selenium webdriver.

```
        <div class="metrick-box">
        <p class="header-title metrics-title">
            <p style="margin: 0px;">ROIC</p>
            <span role="img" aria-label="question-circle" class="anticon anticon-question-circle popover-icon cursor-pointer"><svg viewBox="64 64 896 896" focusable="false" data-icon="question-circle" width="1em" height="1em" fill="currentColor" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M512 64C264.6 64 64 264.6 64 512s200.6 448 448 448 448-200.6 448-448S759.4 64 512 64zm0 820c-205.4 0-372-166.6-372-372s166.6-372 372-372 372 166.6 372 372-166.6 372-372 372z"></path><path d="M623.6 316.7C593.6 290.4 554 276 512 276s-81.6 14.5-111.6 40.7C369.2 344 352 380.7 352 420v7.6c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h48c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8V420c0-44.1 43.1-80 96-80s96 35.9 96 80c0 31.1-22 59.6-56.1 72.7-21.2 8.1-39.2 22.3-52.1 40.9-13.1 19-19.9 41.8-19.9 64.9V620c0 4.4 3.6 8 8 8h48c4.4 0 8-3.6 8-8v-22.7a48.3 48.3 0 0130.9-44.8c59-22.7 97.1-74.7 97.1-132.5.1-39.3-17.1-76-48.3-103.3zM472 732a40 40 0 1080 0 40 40 0 10-80 0z"></path></svg>
            </span>
        </p>
    <div class="_hexagone-shape"><div class="_hexagone"><div class="_innerOuter" style="height: 83%;"><span style="box-sizing: border-box; display: inline-block; overflow: hidden; width: initial; height: initial; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; position: relative; max-width: 100%;"><span style="box-sizing: border-box; display: block; width: initial; height: initial; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; max-width: 100%;"><img alt="" aria-hidden="true" src="data:image/svg+xml;base64,PHN2ZyB3aWR0aD0iNDIiIGhlaWdodD0iNTYiIHhtbG5zPSJodHRwOi8vd3d3LnczLm9yZy8yMDAwL3N2ZyIgdmVyc2lvbj0iMS4xIi8+" style="display: block; max-width: 100%; width: initial; height: initial; background: none; opacity: 1; border: 0px; margin: 0px; padding: 0px;"></span><img alt="" src="/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fgreen.393efa2b.png&amp;w=96&amp;q=75" decoding="async" data-nimg="intrinsic" class="hexa_gone" style="position: absolute; inset: 0px; box-sizing: border-box; padding: 0px; border: none; margin: auto; display: block; width: 0px; height: 0px; min-width: 100%; max-width: 100%; min-height: 100%; max-height: 100%;" srcset="/_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fgreen.393efa2b.png&amp;w=48&amp;q=75 1x, /_next/image?url=%2F_next%2Fstatic%2Fmedia%2Fgreen.393efa2b.png&amp;w=96&amp;q=75 2x"><noscript></noscript></span></div></div></div>
        <p class="_metricsValue">83%</p></div>
```

I have to fetch the value of the class _`metricsValue` which is 83%

In other words I have to implement the logic:
inside class `metrick-box`, inside which if the text of class `header-title metrics-title` is "ROIC", then retrieve the following text of class `metricsValue`

Can someone please advice how to go about implementing this logic, its a bit beyond me to implement in chrome webdriver python.

I get that `driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p[@class='header-title metrics-title']").text` is 'ROIC', but I am not able to implement this logic of getting the value of `metricsValue` which is 83% when it matches. There are several parameters like this, so I have to implement this logic.

I am trying in the follwing way:

```
 if driver.find_element(By.XPATH,"//p[@class='header-title metrics-title']").text == 'ROIC'
       <find the value of following class "metricsValue">
```

Any idea will be appreciated